# How to use my windows 7 laptop as router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing

I would like to route my mobile traffic through my laptop which its operating system is windows 7 professional.

Now my laptop is connected to internet using LAN and is also connected to the access point which I want to connect my mobile to internet through following way:

mobile --> access point --> laptop -->(LAN) internet

I have enabled windows routing in registry and also start routing and remote access service.

But my mobile couldn't connect to internet.

The access point : 192.168.2.1

Laptop LAN : 192.168.1.10

Laptop Wireless : 192.168.2.50

I try to add routing rule, but the rules which I use fail.

So, How can I route the traffic?

Comment: See this article http://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/home-computer-router/ in case it helps with the ICS being needed potentially.

Answer (score 0):

Only routing is not enough. You need enabling routing and NAT on your Windows 7 box.

Windows 7 has a built-in NAT function called ICS. You may try it.

Also, you may try to install any router software to achieve your goal. Personally, I use GNS3 to simulate the Cisco router so that I can get a lot of features.